Корректное использование сессий в SQLAlchemy
На основе докумментации сформировал фабрику подключения к БД:
from sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

url_object = URL.create(
    f"{os.environ['DIALECT']}+{os.environ['DRIVER']}",
    username=os.environ['USERNAME'],
    password=os.environ['PASSWORD'], 
    host=os.environ['HOST'],
    port=int(os.environ['PORT']),
    database=os.environ['DB'],
)

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
engine = create_engine(url_object, pool_size=10, max_overflow=15)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))

правильно ли я понял, что теперь можно будет в любом модуле использовать db_session для работы с БД только его импортировав в нужное место другого модуля?:
db_session.add(...)
db_session.commit()
db_session.close() # это можно не вызывать, т.к.

либо
with db_session() as session_db:
    session_db.add(...)
    session_db.commit()

Или мне надо было организовать фабрику сессий в отдельной функци типа такого:
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session
...
engine = create_engine(url_object, pool_size=10, max_overflow=15)

def db_session() -> Session:
    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        return db
    finally:
        db.close()

Ну и также работать:
db_session.add(...)
db_session.commit()
db_session.close() # это можно не вызывать, т.к.

либо
with db_session() as session_db:
    session_db.add(...)
    session_db.commit()

но, тогда получается что закрытие сессии бы дублировалось? Или я что-то путаю?

finally: db.close() эээ, но это же сразу закроет сессию, ещё до выхода из функции. Вы точно понимаете, как finally работает? )

А вообще если по той доке походить, то лучший способ всё-таки через with db_session() as session_db: - это вообще обычно лучший паттерн для работы с объектами, которые поддерживают контекстные менеджеры.

@CrazyElf, ну finaly отрабатывает после успешно выполненного блока try или except . Там надо было вместо return  напистаь yeild.

Я же правильно понимаю, что использовать db_session.close() нельзя при использовании scoped_session(), т.к. он сам закрывает сессии и если я сам еще закрою, то будет ошибка?

В доках там вообще session.remove() используется, я сам не до конца понял некоторые моменты там.

Вообще говоря, в алхимии сессия хранит отображенные объекты. Если вы закрываете сессию, то объекты, загруженные из базы или сохранённые в базу, теряются. ИМХО лучше иметь одну постоянную сессию на всё приложение, чтобы потом при попытках изменить объект или считать атрибут объекта не удивляться ошибкам вида 'Instance is not bound to a Session'

@PakUula Ну это смотря какой стиль работы с данными. Для серьёзных приложений держать всё в памяти не очень хорошо. Мало ли что рухнет, все изменения пропадут. Хороший стиль это открыл сессию, прочитал, изменил, записал, закрыл сессию. А если что-то в памяти нужно, то открыл, прочитал, преобразовал в объекты, не зависящие от сессии, закрыл сессию.
